# Taking the output of a checklist in Microsoft Forms and using Power Automate to turn it into a bulleted list that can be sent to a Teams channel

Tags: html, microsoft-teams, power-automate, microsoft-forms

As the title states, I am trying to take a checklist from Forms and transform it into a bulleted list. So far, I have been able to format the checklist with line breaks after separating the array into multiple lines, as shown below.

[image: Progress so far]

The problem that I am having at the moment is the fact that I would like to add bullets to said list, and I am not sure how. I've tried to use the join function with HTML's  tag, but I quickly realized that it's obviously not going to work that way.

[image: Attempt to make a bulleted list with "join"]

So my question is, how do I turn what I have now into a bulleted list? Should I make a loop with Power Automate? Or is there a better way to do it? (I'm very new to Power Automate and HTML)

[image: Power Automate Flow]

This is the line of code I used to separate the array:

```
json(outputs('Get_response_details')?['formExampleID'])
```

If there is anything that I'm missing, I apologize and I would be happy to provide. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please refer these docs: 1. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Bullet-button-in-e-mail-designer-is-formatting-the-entire-body/td-p/520138   2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/apply-to-each

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track. I'm not familiar with the json function, so if that can be put into an array you can use this solution.

Otherwise, use the `split()` function on the `Get_response_details` and loop that into an array.
Then, for the length of the array, using a loop, use `concat('•   ',first(array[i]))` while putting however many spaces after the bullet that you want. I put 3 in this example.
Then you simply do another loop for (or build into the same loop) your output.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).